# Android Accelerometer to show GForce of break and turn of a car

Tags: android, accelerometer

creating a program to see the gforce of my car i have a problem.
I can read the x, y,z values of the accelerometer but how can i get the gforce from there.

I read some like sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z) but i want to have the gforce in x and in y.

Should i use Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION or Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION?

Target of the tool is to have something like the G-Meter in aDyno.

Comment: The linear acceleration is the one you are looking for. There is a typo in your question, you ask: "Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION or Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION", that is the same thing twice.

Answer (score 0):

use Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
the result values will be the acceleration minus gravity acceleration.